# Flutter - Possible to create a stream from two collections?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter application I'm trying to display a user's saved posts using a stream. I'll need to get the id from a collection called postings, and try to match it from an array named savedPostingIDs in another collection named users. I have streams throughout the app, but I haven't been able to figure this out because I'm trying to get info from two different collections.

An example of a stream I have on a page would be:

```
      _stream = Firestore.instance
          .collection('postings')
          .where('type', isEqualTo: 'Arts & Culture')
          .snapshots();
    }
  }
```

The above stream will grab info from a cartain category I have on the app. I've tried different variations of the code above with no luck. This is my first flutter app, first time using firebase so any help and advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

[Here is an image that will show the information I'm trying to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgQZo.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could potentially use either the [`flatMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/FlatMapExtension/flatMap.html) operator or the [`combineLatest2`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) operator from the [`RxDart`](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package in order to achieve your desired outcome.

The code sample below finds the posting where the type is equal to "Arts & Culture" and then transforms that posting into a list of users where the saved posting ids array contains that posting's id.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('postings')
            .where(
              'type',
              isEqualTo: 'Arts & Culture',
            )
            .snapshots()
            .flatMap((value) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where(
                  'savedPostingIDs',
                  arrayContains: value.docs.first.id,
                )
                .snapshots()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].id),
                  ),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code sample below combines the user where the id is equal to the "INSERT_USER_ID_HERE" and the posting where the type is equal to "Arts & Culture" into a single stream of saved posting ids.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: Rx.combineLatest2<QuerySnapshot, QuerySnapshot, List<String>>(
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where(
                'id',
                isEqualTo: 'INSERT_USER_ID_HERE',
              )
              .snapshots(),
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('postings')
              .where(
                'type',
                isEqualTo: 'Arts & Culture',
              )
              .snapshots(),
          (a, b) {
            final user = a.docs.first.data();
            final posting = b.docs.first.data();

            return (user['savedPostingIDs'] as List<String>)
                .where((element) => element == posting['id'])
                .toList();
          },
        ),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                  ),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any issues running either of the code samples above, or have any questions whatsoever, then don't hesitate to let me know as I am happy to help!

Comment: Thank you for your response.Haven't had any luck with it so far. When I import rxdart, I get this error error: 
'The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. '

The main reason I was trying to load the stream for saved users is because the app loads slowly if I try loading it with an async function when I start it up. 
Would it be possible to do a function I already have (getSaved() for example) somewhere after nav push? : 
`
currentUser.getLoginPush().whenComplete(() {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page()));
        });
`

Comment: Apologies that you are experiencing issues with the code samples, is there any chance that you might be able to share more of your code or share a link to your project in order for us to gain a better understanding of the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Thank you again for you help. Here is a link with 2 dart files, and 1 txt explaining what I'm trying to do. It's different than what I originally asked in the question, but I have been having diffuclty with creating the stream for this. Link: https://gist.github.com/heidio/602be62cf23f163242a8f4f4204b1e0e